# Can I empty the console screen buffer when it reaches the size limit?

Tags: java, windows, logging, tail, windows-console

I have a Java program running on Windows Command Prompt (java -jar file.jar) that logs to the console and also to a file. At some point it stops showing logs in the console but not the file. I guess that's because the console window buffer size limit is reached. How can I reset or empty this buffer when it reaches the size limit, so that the console can continue printing log output? I don't care about losing the previous log because I have it in the log file.

The fact is that if I press Ctrl-C it starts printing the log again.

Thanks.

Comment: This is what it should do automatically already.

Comment: You set a buffer size in properties, and CMD keeps the last n lines and throw earlier lines away.

Comment: @CatCat, yes except it's not CMD but the console host (e.g. conhost.exe) that does this. If we happen to run a console program from CMD (as opposed to some other shell or directly from Explorer), its only thread is blocked while waiting for the child to exit. There's nothing special about CMD; it's just like any program that uses a console.